# Разработка мобильного приложения для ТСД Атол Smart.Lite (Android 7)

Tags: java, android

подскажите пожалуйста, занимался ли кто-нибудь разработкой моб приложений для ТСД на андроиде? Интересует конкретно кусок кода который отвечает за сканирование, то есть, как в код интегрируется использование ЛАЗЕРНОГО СЧИТЫВАТЕЛЯ!! и как подключить кнопку "SCAN" для дальнейшего программирования?

Приложение в моем случае должно считать штрих код и записать результат в EditText, все просто, если делать это приложение для телефона с камерой, но на ТСД нет камеры, а есть только лазер...

Разработку делаю в Android Studio на языке Java

Comment: Как правило у производителей таких устройств есть библиотека для общения со сканером, которую просто нужно интегрировать. Также вероятно сканер работает просто как устройство ввода.

Comment: библиотека есть, но толк от нее не большой...

Comment: что вы имеете ввиду под устройством ввода, можете пожалуйста подробнее объяснить как объявить и использовать его в коде?

Comment: Часто сканеры интерпретируются устройством как обычная клавиатура. Значит достаточно просто отследить в активити нажатые клавиши

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что информацию необходимо искать у производителя.